# EF Core Identity User new One to One relationships

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

I'm having these entities: User, Address and Company. The User is the main entity and each user has one Mailing Address and a Company  (one to one relationship)

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    // code
    // Company relationship
    public Company Company { get; set; }

    // Mailing Address relationship
    public Address MailingAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //code here    

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //code here  

   [ForeignKey("User")]
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public User User { get; set; }
```

}

and here is the DbContext

```
public class AuthentificationContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public AuthentificationContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options){}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .Ignore(user => user.ConcurrencyStamp)
            .Ignore(user => user.LockoutEnabled)
            .Ignore(user => user.LockoutEnd);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOne<Address>(u => u.MailingAddress)
            .WithOne(a => a.User)
            .HasForeignKey<Address>(a => a.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOne<Company>(u => u.Company)
            .WithOne(c => c.User)
            .HasForeignKey<Company>(c => c.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User");
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> MailingAddresses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that the Id inside the IdentityUser is of type string and cannot be overwritten to be of int type. What should I do? Remove the inheritance from the IdentityUser or try to change the foreign keys to be of type string?

Also, is my approach correct?

Thanks!

Comment: *Remove the inheritance from the IdentityUser* -- yes! Let your own user refer to IdentityUser as the only connection between your BL and ASP.Net identity.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you probably need to do is change the UserId property in your `Address` and `Company` classes to be a `string` instead of an `int`. that user ID will need to be the same type as the primary key of your User class, which is a string if you inherit directly from `IdentityUser`. (It's actually the email address of the user - maybe not optimal for the default from microsoft, but that's another discussion). So your classes start to look like this:

```cs
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    // code
    // Company relationship
    public Company Company { get; set; }

    // Mailing Address relationship
    public Address MailingAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //code here    

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //code here  

   [ForeignKey("User")]
   public string UserId { get; set; }
   public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Your Fluent API relationships appear to be correct, so this should get you moving.

A more advanced approach (though probably better) is to override the primary key type in your User class to an `int`. [This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1#customize-the-model) will take you to the documentation on how to modify and extend your User model, and if you read down from the link point you'll see "How to change the primary key". I almost always change the key to an `int` or `long` value instead of a string, as in my eyes it's just cleaner. The docs use a GUID, but the type is up to you, as long as it can be enforced as unique and can be compared for lookup operations the type can be whatever you want.

Hope this helps.